# js, log object is different to log 'string' + obj

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm logging a jQuery object, which assigns to

```
eg: $obj = <div></div>
```

if I

```
 log $obj
```

I get ''

```
 <div></div>
```

, which is what I need. But when  I

```
 Log 'some string' + $obj
```

I  get this

```
  [ object, object]
```

which is not what I want. How do I get the normal log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `+`; that will convert both to strings, giving you an unhelpful representation. Instead, pass two arguments into `console.log`:

```
console.log('a string', $obj);
```